Spark Kinesis Stream Scala Example trying to follow Spark Documentation but does not produce output
I am trying to process data from Kinesis stream using Spark streaming.
I am using https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kinesis-integration.html as reference to write code
object TimeAndLanFixer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[6]").setAppName("LangAndTimeZoneFixer")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(3))


    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(s"Current time in millis: $time")
    val lang = System.getProperty("user.language")
    println(s"Current language: $lang")
    val initialPositionTimestamp = "2024-06-27 00:00:00"
    val date: Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(initialPositionTimestamp)
    val kinesisStream = KinesisInputDStream.builder
      .streamName(System.getenv("STREAM_NAME"))
      .streamingContext(ssc)
      .endpointUrl("https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
      .regionName("us-west-2")
      .checkpointAppName("DebugApp").checkpointInterval(Seconds(10))
      .storageLevel(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
      .initialPosition(new AtTimestamp(date))
      .metricsEnabledDimensions(KinesisClientLibConfiguration.DEFAULT_METRICS_ENABLED_DIMENSIONS.asScala.toSet)
      .build()


    kinesisStream.start()

    kinesisStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      rdd.foreach(println)
    })

    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }

}


When I run this,I don't see any output on console in Intellij. I just see two println that i added in program. My input kinesis stream has 5 shards and based on some of reading that I did on internet,if testing locally,we need to supply a number more than number of shards (local[6]) to process data locally. Program is still not moving ahead
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
<!--    <scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


Missing link was
ssc.start()
It seems weird that u need to call ssc.start() as well in addition to kinesis.start()
Facing a lot of young GEN GC issues but that is for other post
Regards
Bhanu
Regards
Bhanu
